# Multiple file uploads through a single input

Tags: magento-1.7, php, forms, file-upload

I have created a form in frontend where sellers can fill their details but for brands logo, I want them to upload all the logos through a single input.How can I do that?
Code:
form-
__('Brand Logo') ?>

Controller:
foreach($_FILES["logopic"]["tmp_name"] as $key=>$tmp_name){
                    if(strlen($_FILES['logopic']['name'])>0){
                        $image = getimagesize($_FILES['logopic']['tmp_name']);
                        if($image['mime']) {
                            $img2 = rand(1,99999).$_FILES["logopic"]["name"];
                    $target= Mage::getBaseDir().'/media/Seller_Profile/BrandsLogo';
                            $uploader = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader('logopic'); 
                            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png'));
                            $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
                            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false); 
                            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                            $saved = $uploader->save($target,$img2);
                            if($saved){
                                $value->setlogopic($img2);
                            }
                        }else{
                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__("Disallowed file type."));
                        }
                    } }

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 - edit input field

```
<input type="file" name="filefield" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: I have tried this and added for loop in controller but the file is not  saved

Comment: But can You get files in $_POST ?

Comment: Didn't get you. Can you explain

Comment: Need to check what You get in controller side   $this->getRequest()->getParam('your-file-field-name')

Comment: wait let me upload the complete code!!!!

Comment: added code please check